# Turning off EOP connector during maintenance

Tags: email-server, microsoft-office-365, smarthost

I have a virtual mail server in house protected by Exchange Online Protection, and it has been running well for the last few months. Over the weekend, the hosts that host the VM will be taken down, as will most of the network, for a rewire and other upgrades. During this time, is there a way to tell EOP not to try deliver email to my domain, but to hold it till the I say its safe? I think EOP will keep mail if the receiving server is offline, but I am not sure for how long. So, how do i pause this? I can see an option to disable the connector, but what happens to mail for the domain then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default mail deferral limit in the internet is 2 days if not configured differently. As you can see in [this technet link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-protection-limits.aspx), this is the same for EOP:

> **Message deferral limit:**   Messages in deferral will remain in our queues for **2 days**. Message retry attempts are based on the error type received from the recipient’s mail system. Messages are retried every 15 minutes.

Comment: While I can't think of a way to "set" a switch in EOP, if you the interface to the server is not available to it - it should hold them. So temporarily blocking it at a firewall, or changing the vNIC so it can't respond would essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it did queue up all my email while the network was down (managed to do it with minimum downtime) and when the mail server came back online, all email came in soon after.